# Handle Multiple GIT Account

Tags: git, github

I've my own git account and two git accounts of different client. I'm trying to commit, push or pull from my account but it gives an error of `"permission to git is denied."` Could any one guide me how to handle multiple git account.

Thanks

Comment: How are you pushing to the various accounts?  Did Git even prompt you for a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, this tutorial is for linux users.
http://mherman.org/blog/2013/09/16/managing-multiple-github-accounts/#.WE0XEVy77DU

Answer (score 0):

I do this with the following trick.

in `~/.ssh/config`

have lines similar to this

```
Host gh-account1
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/account1_rsa
Host gh-account2
    HostName 176.126.246.157
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/account2_rsa
```

Then instead of the URL github give you use gh-account2:user/repo.git
(This is the clone with ssh url but `git@github.com` replaced with `gh-account2`)

if you need to push to the same repo with 2 accounts you will need to add multiple remotes

```
git remote add account1 account1:user/repo.git
```

then you can go

```
git push account1 <branch>
```

you can do this with https linsk (they ask for account name and password each time) but its a lot of typing just to push code

Answer (score 0):

- Go to ~/.ssh
- Create a file named config(have no extension )
- Open config file & add below codes. (change according to your account)

  1. Account 1

     ```
     # account_1
     Host gitlab.com-account_1
     HostName gitlab.com
     User git
     PreferredAuthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_account_1
     ```
  2. Account 2

     ```
     # Account2
     Host gitlab.com-Account2
     HostName gitlab.com
     User git
     PreferredAuthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_Account2
     ```
  3. Account 3

     ```
     # Account_3
     Host github.com
     HostName github.com
     User git
     PreferredAuthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_Account_3
     ```
- Add remote url as follows

  1. Account 1

     ```
     git remote add origin git@gitlab.com-account_1:group_name/repo_name.git
     ```
  2. Account 2

     ```
     git remote add origin git@gitlab.com-Account2:group_name/repo_name.git
     ```
  3. Account 3

     ```
     git remote add origin git@github.com:github_username/repo_name.git
     ```

> Make sure that IdentityFile names are same as you created during ssh key generation.